# Summing two inputs to a third input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum

I want to the third input to change when the first two inputs are changed.

I want to do something like: (input1 + input2) x 0.23

So, this is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var one = '#delegate'.value;
        var two = '#accompanying2'.value;
        var three = (one + two) * 0.23;
        $('#vat_input').val(three);
    });
</script>
```

Where am I doing it wrong? THe syntax?

Comment: Try one = $("#delegate").value; two = $("#accompanying2").value;

Comment: LOOK HOW YOU SET THE VALUE, use that same syntax for reading the value. You also need to change the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the value contents of #delegate, etc are strings, you would need to parse them (e.g. as floats) before performing the maths.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var one = parseFloat($('#delegate').val());
    var two = parseFloat($('#accompanying2').val());
    var three = (one + two) * 0.23;
    $('#vat_input').val(three);
});
```